# mean = 17, median = m, m-17 =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, order-statistics

I am not sure if this is solvable, I think I saw it somewhere if this question is not clear enough and missing information I would gladly remove it!

**if** the mean of an arithmetic consecutive numbers = $17$ and the median = $m$ $$mean = 17$$ $$median = m$$
what is $m-17$ = ?

Thanks for taking the time to read the question !

Comment: what has been tried, what is known ?

Comment: Have you tried examples?  Can you find a string of consecutive numbers with mean $17$?  What is their median?

Comment: The key here must be what you call "an arithmetic consecutive numbers".

Comment: Special case: Try one number! What about $3$ numbers? But two numbers (assuming consecutive integers) is not possible -- why?

Comment: It certainly seems that there is enough information.  As I say...have you tried examples?  If you had, I think you'd have spotted a pattern.

Comment: There is enough information, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: The median is always equal to the mean !
is that always the case in an arithmetic sequence ?

Comment: Correct. It is often easy to think about the arithmetic sequence with respect to the median as opposed to the first term.

Comment: but this is only true of arithmetic sequences.  An arithmetic sequence is one where the terms are equal distance so the average is in the middle (so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

The hard way to do it that the sequence is $b, b+ d, b+ 2d, b+3d, ..... , b+ n*d$.

The mean is $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n (b + dk)}{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)b + d\sum_{k=0}^n k}{n+1}$

$= b + \frac d{n+1}*\frac {n(n+1)}{2} = b + \frac {nd}2$.

The median is $b + $ halfway between $0$ and $n*d$ $= b+ \frac {nd}2$.

So mean - median = $0$.

The easy way to do it:

Let there be a sequence of $n = 2k + 1$ arithmetically sequential numbers.  Let $m$ be the middle number.  Let $m - k*d$ be the least and $m + kd$ be the greatest.  $m$ is the middle and thus the median.

If you pair the terms up, the least ($m - k*d$) to the greatest ($m + k*d$) and the $j$th least $m - (k-j)d$ to the $j$th greatest ($m + (k-j)d$) then the average of each pair is $m$ and the average of all the terms is $m$.

So $m$ is both the median and the mean.  So median - mean = $0$.

If the sequence has an even number $n = 2k$ terms, there won't be a middle term but the middle two terms will be $m - d/2$ and $m+d/2$ for some $m$ beings some mid point.  The median with be $m $.

The terms all pair up with $m - d/2 - jd$ pairing with $m + d/2 + jd$.  So the pairs add to $2m$ and average to $m$.  So the mean is $m$>

So $m$ is both the median and the mean again.